# Different nameservers for different networks

Tags: 12.04, laptop, dns, resolv.conf

I use Ubuntu 12.04 on my work laptop. Currently I live abroad and I only have this one computer, and I take it home after work to use as my personal computer. The problem is that the nameserver used on the office network differs from the nameserver on my own network at home.

At the office I need to use `10.4.180.250`, and at home I need to use `192.168.1.1`.

My **/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf** has this line in it:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
```

When I connect to the work network I need to manually change my `resolv.conf` and change the `nameserver` to `10.4.180.250`. Then I connect to another office in another country with a VPN, and the resolv.conf gets reset and I need to change the `nameserver` back to `10.4.180.250` again.

Is it possible to always have both nameservers in my resolv.conf by using multiple `prepend`s?

```
prepend domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
prepend domain-name-servers 10.4.180.250;
```

or:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1 10.4.180.250;
```

Are there disadvantages to having a nameserver that is "invalid" for the current network? It there a better way to do it?

Comment: If it's invalid , it won't get used. As long as you can't access `192.168.1.1` at work , what you are doing is right

Comment: Have you tried having two 'named' connections, with differnet details for you two sites?  Is the '192.168.1.1' your own (wireless) router?

Comment: @david6: What are named connections? Yes, that's my own wireless router.

Comment: see my answer ..

Answer (score 0):

***Add two connection profiles: (eg. repeat twice.)***

Setup a new interface with the settings you need:

- (right-click) on Network icon (up/down arrows)
- select Edit Connections
- first select tab for 'Wired' or 'Wireless', then click on 'Add'
- enter the name for this new connection (eg. 'home' / 'office')
- select 'IPv4 settings'
- method: 'Manual'
- DNS Servers: (add 192.168.1.1 for 'home')
- click 'Save'

**Note:** *You may need to manually assign a IP address, mask, etc..*

Comment: I do it this way.  But rather than selecting "Manual", I choose "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only", and fill in only the DNS servers, but not the IP addreses; those are set by DHCP. I have one set to use Google's DNS server, so I put "8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4" in for the two DNS addresses.